# A junk mail that don't want to be deleted

Tags: mail.app, email

I got a strage behaviour on my Mail.app:

In my Junk mail folder I see an email of Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) coming from this email address: phuonghm@baria.baria-vungtau.gov.vn

It's obviously a spam email, and the I delete it each times that I found it. But some days ago I observe that the email arrival date it's always the same, and this means that each times I delete it, email come back from the trash and return to the junk folder.

The most freaky things is that this email is ONLY in my Mac. In my iPhone and on iCloud.com there's not trace of this email.

Could this be some spyware of something?
How I can (try) to finally delete it?

*PS: When I delete it I also empty the trash.*
*PPS: On Mail this email is set as junk.*

#### Infos:

- MacBook Pro mid 2010
- OSX 10.10.3
- Mail.app 8.2 (2098)

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the Mailbox menu and clicking "Rebuild". This will rebuild your mailbox and hopefully fix the problem.

Note: This process may take some time depending on the number of messages in your mailbox

Comment: I have the Italian GUI, therefor I need to find the "Rebuild" button... ;) I will tell you if this solution works. Thanks!